# What is the retrieval performance of tuple as values in a hashmap in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, tuples

I have a hash map, using string as key, values are list of strings of size 2. I am trying to get the fastest performance time when getting the values back. The values will always contain only 2 strings. The question are:

1. what is the best container in this use case? List or Tuple?
2. What is the retrieval performance of tuple in Scala? is it equal to/faster than list?

By the way, I couldn't find anything on Scala tuple's performance. Please share if you know of any.

Comment: Surely your question is more about map performance, not tuple performance...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the question to clarify. I meant to say the performance of getting the value from map depends on the type of container used for the values. For example, if I use a hashmap as values instead of tuple/list. I am sure that would impact the retrieval performance of the values.

Comment: I can't see why. At the end it is just returning a reference to the value. I would expect tuple vs. List for the value to make no significant difference.  For the key, it would be different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a Tuple of two things, you will be using the case class [Tuple2](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Tuple2.scala). As you can see, it is just a class that takes two parameters to instantiate.

If you're concerned about the performance of Lists versus Tuples, I suggest you write a benchmark. I find using [ScalaMeter](https://scalameter.github.io/) exceedingly useful when doing that. I suspect the performance of both will be the same.

If you're concerned about readability and reasonability of your code, I would suggest using a Tuple. If the values will **always** contain two values, then using Tuple2 is the better choice. Using a List implies that it could potentially contain less, or more, than two.

Comment: List will always have an extra overhead of extracting the second member. In Tuple both the members presence is guaranteed, and both can be extracted in same amount of time. So, Tuple is better for storage. However, for *retrieval* from map, it doesn't much any difference because that is a property of the `Map` implementation being used.

Comment: @tuxdna can you please clarify what you meant by "List will always have an extra overhead of extracting the second member."? What is the overhead you're taking about?

Comment: @Z-1: Assuiming `l = List()` has two elements, then first element can be obtained using `first = l.head`. However for the second element, you need to do do `second = l.tail.head`. Note here that `second` element takes more operations, because `l` is a linked list. However for a tuple `t = (x,y)`, both `first = t._1` and `second = t._2`, require same time to fetch. For huge amount of data, this does make a lot of difference.